# Servlet program compile time error with tomcat7 and server start error with tomcat6

Tags: servlets

Hi can anyone please give me the solution for this problem.....

While compiling a servelt program with tomcat7 am getting error as:

> Cannot access javax.servlet.Servlet, bad class file:c:program files\Apache software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\servlet-api.jar(javax/servlet/Servlet.class) class file has wrong version 50.0, should be 49.0. Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

```
public class Servletprgm implements Servlet{"
```

I have set Classpath to the correct location, am not able to find a solution for this error. I thought there might be an error while installing so I thought of installing tomcat6 and with that also am having the problem, when am starting tomcat6 its getting stooped automatically...

Answer (score 0):

This comes from the class version. If you try to load something compiled for java 6 in a java 5 runtime you'll get the error, incompatible class version, got 50, expected 49.

See http://javarevisited.blogspot.jp/2011/07/javalangunsupportedclassversionerror.html

Some class versions are backwardly compatbible and some are not.

- Java 1.2 uses major version 46
- Java 1.3 uses major version 47
- Java 1.4 uses major version 48
- Java 5 uses major version 49
- Java 6 uses major version 50

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, now i could able to compile my program....There is problem with the server as am opening it its getting started and getting closed automatically by itself

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

public class Servletprgm **extends** GenericServlet
{
public service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) throws IOException
{
..........//Code Here//...........
}
}

Comment: Please expand on why this is the correct answer to the question.